# Ubuntu 16.04 disk partitioning , app installation and /boot cleaning

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, wine, boot-partition

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop a few days ago (first os on this pc) and I have some problems understanding how disk partitions should be handled.

[image: My disk partition scheme]

I created `/dev/sda3` when I installed Ubuntu, `/dev/sda5` is supposed to be my boot partition.

I created `/dev/sda2` hoping that I could move all apps & personal files there by making it my `/home` partition.

I can add files in `/home` but apps are still installed in `/dev/sda5` and are starting to pile up.

Also, I used wine to try and install some `.exe` apps, after uninstalling them using Uninstall wine software I am left with lots of GBs of data in my partition which I can't figure out how to remove.

How can I download packages into my `/home` partition (or in any other partition)?

How can I clean up my `/boot` partition? Could it be a problem if I didn't?

Comment: You can (and should) not install applications in `/home`. It is precisely defined in each package where all the files must go, which means you can not change that unless you download source code tarballs, modify them and compile them yourself - which will just mess your package system up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your partition table:

1. Your `$HOME` partition is correctly configured and detected as such by the OS. As for downloading packages, anything you download using your browser or external downloaders will get downloaded to your `$HOME` partition. But the packages downloaded for upgrades get downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. That's how apt works, you can't change that but don't worry because once the upgrades are installed, those files get deleted automatically.
2. You do not have a seperate partition for `/boot`.
3. To delete residual files or folders of `wine` do:

   ```
   sudo find / -type f -iname '*wine*'; sudo find / -type d -iname '*wine*'
   ```

   That should bring up almost all of the residues of Wine. Delete those to free up some space.
4. Also you might run the following command to remove any other residues from any other applications.

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get clean
   ```
5. Finally, install `bleachbit` and run it twice (once as user and once as root) to free up some more space from your hard-drive.

Comment: `apt-get autoclean` is a subset of `apt-get clean`, so running both consecutively is useless. However, neither this nor `bleachbit` is normally needed and I would consider this superfluous.